# Orscoreci R function question, confidence interval for odds ratio

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, confidence-interval

I was given the next exercise:

In a Retrospective case-control study we measure the Association between lung cancer and smoking.

709 cases and 709 controls were selected, and the exposition was measured as a binary whether the subject ever was a smoker.

```
Predictor  Disease1 Disease2 Total
  Exposed1      688      650  1338
  Exposed2       21       59    80
  Total         709      709  1418
```

I was requested to calculate the OR and its 95% confidence interval.
First, I did it by hand and I got the next results:

```
ln(odds ratio)+- z alpha/2(SE):
ln(2.97)+-1.96(0.2599)

-> 1.089+1.96(0.2599) = 1.5984
-> 1.089-1.96(0.2599) = 0.5795
```

- Confidence intervals:

  (exp(0.5795), exp(1.5984)) = (e^0.5795, e^1.5984) = (1.78 , 4.94)

So far, all clear, now, I need to do it in R, the instructor told me I had to use the function orscoreci in this way:

```
library('PropCIs')
orscoreci(688, 709, 650, 709, conf.level = 0.95)
```

My question is: Why should I use the total values 709, 709 instead of 21, 59 in the function if I did not consider these totals when I calculated the result by hand?

Thanks! :)

Exercise result by hand: (1.78 , 4.94)
Exercise result on R: (1.78 , 4.94)

Question related to the `orscoreci` function in R. How the function works.

Comment: R is open source and you can access any function's source code. If you type the function name and run (with no parenthesis, only the function name) you will see the function source code. In the case of `orscoreci` the first two instructions are `px = x1/n1` and `py = x2/n2`. Does this answer the question?

Comment: first thing to do before using any function in r is ``?function_name`` in your case ``?orscoreci``